# Android input connection error

Tags: android

I am connecting my android client emulator to server(Servlet). The output stream is working fine. Server is printing the message sent from client. Server is sending response successfully. But the android input connection is passive. Here the error shown in logcat

```
showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

What is the problem?

I am sorry `showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection` is not an error.logcat shows  this even if the app is working fine.

Its a strange situation. From class A I am going to class C and from class C i am able to connect to server and get the response back. But If i go to class C from Class B, I am only able to send the request from C to server but I am unable to get response from the server. Server is working all fine.
  Class A to C to server(request and response both)  works fine when class A does not open any connection with the server itself. 
But Class A to C to server(only request) works if the class A itself first opens a connection to the server and based on the response moves to class C.

 This is what I was able to find out after lot of trial and error.

Comment: @Shishir Shetty : Its a strange situation. From class A I am going to class C and from class C i am able to connect to server and get the response back. But If i go to class C from Class B, I am only able to send the request from C to server but I am unable to get response from the server. Server is working all fine. I am getting the above mentioned error in client side

Comment: Sometimes you must Close the KEYBOARD, before closing the activity...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Such problems occur when the input connection in the previous page(or class) has not been closed. Check whether you've closed the input connection in the previous class
(by giving `connection.close()`).

Comment: Oh sheesh!!!! Yea I actually forgot to close the connection in Class B. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where do you put connection.close ?