# Transmit and Receive Socket Implementation in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am currently developing socket communication between android and server, which is a simple java program run in terminal. Things are going well except there is a warning always appears in the logCat when I close the application:

```
IInputConnectionWrapper    showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

I am searching on the internet to find out the problem I found a post in StackOverflow [Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633188/android-input-connection-error). The difference is that I can send and receive information well in my program. The answer to this similar problem is that connection is not closed. Does that mean I didn't call `socket.close();` after operation? That leads to a more complicated problem of implementation.

First of all,  I want a single, static socket to listen and send to a server. Because I might not close the socket every time I transmit something, so I just close it after the listener finishes the work.

Detail codes are posted below

I initialize connection in the constructor as:

```
client = new Socket(mServerName, mport);
out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()); 
inFromServer = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
reader = new BufferedReader(inFromServer);
```

And let them be there during the whole process.

I wrote transmitting from android to server into a function as following:

```
public void sendRequest(int type, int what1, int what2, Object data)
{
    try{
        if(client.isConnected())
        {
            out.writeUTF(encoded(type,what1,what2,data) + "\n");            
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException at SendRequest");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Listener in a new thread:

```
try {       
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            ReceiveHandler(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException at StartListen");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try { 
         // The Only Place that I close the Socket
            inFromServer.close();
            out.close();
            reader.close();
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Close Socket with IOException " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

My Question is:

> Is there something wrong with my implementation or are there better ways to do this?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool that can help you diagnose network related issues both on Android devices and in the emulator. It may help you to track down the issue a bit further. The ARO tool is open source and available here http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=9700312

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will be to your any use or not.. but i am giving you the code i used for client server communication..

**Client Side code:**

```
public class ClientWala {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Boolean b = true;
    Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);

    System.out.println("connected: "+s.isConnected());


    OutputStream output = s.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(output,true);

    // to write data to server
    while(b){

        if (!b){

             System.exit(0);
        }

        else {
            pw.write(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
        }
    }


    // to read data from server
    InputStream input   = s.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(input);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String data = null;

    while ((data = br.readLine())!=null){

        // Print it using sysout, or do whatever you want with the incoming data from server

    }




    }
}
```

**Server side code:**

```
import java.io.*
import java.net.*;


public class ServerTest {

    ServerSocket s;

    public void go() {

        try {
            s = new ServerSocket(44457);

            while (true) {

                Socket incoming = s.accept();
                Thread t = new Thread(new MyCon(incoming));
                t.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    class MyCon implements Runnable {

        Socket incoming;

        public MyCon(Socket incoming) {

            this.incoming = incoming;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream(),
                        true);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                        incoming.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String inp = null;

                boolean isDone = true;

                System.out.println("TYPE : BYE");
                System.out.println();
                while (isDone && ((inp = br.readLine()) != null)) {

                    System.out.println(inp);
                    if (inp.trim().equals("BYE")) {
                        System.out
                                .println("THANKS FOR CONNECTING...Bye for now");
                        isDone = false;
                        s.close();
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                try {
                    s.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ServerTest().go();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! But in your program you are sending information by listening to the console. What I want is I can call function send message from other classes. Do you have any ideas about this? Thank you all the same!