# How to solve showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

Tags: android

When I close my app I get this message on LogCat
 `showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection`

I read somewhere, but I'm not sure, that it means that I didn't release something, something related to the memory usage.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Pls check this link for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633188/android-input-connection-error

Comment: you may be using a custom softkeyboard . I mean have you installed a softkeyboard in your mobile ?

Comment: The warning appeared when the soft keyboard was activated in one of my EditTexts and the activity lose focus.

Comment: Sometimes you must Close the KEYBOARD, before closing the activity...

Answer (score 0):

Such problems occur when the input connection in the previous page(or class) has not been closed. Check whether you've closed the input connection in the previous class (by giving `connection.close()`).

from

[Android input connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633188/android-input-connection-error)

Comment: Sorry for the naive question, but since I'm just calling a webservice URL through HttpPost/HttpClient, where do I place this `connection.close()` statement? And what is `connection` variable?

Comment: @VikramV That is dependant on your implementation. You should place the close where you are completely done using the connection (ie. after results are returned) and connection is the client variable (ie. httpClient).

Answer (score 0):

**from the documentation**

The InputConnection interface is the communication channel from an InputMethod back to the application that is receiving its input. It is used to perform such things as reading text around the cursor, committing text to the text box, and sending raw key events to the application.

**In addition, further reading shows**

getExtractedText(): This method may fail either if the input connection has become invalid (such as its process crashing) or the client is taking too long to respond with the text (it is given a couple seconds to return). In either case, a null is returned.

It appears to also monitor changes to such text, and alert changes.

To hunt the issue down you'll have to explore any queries you are making, perhaps around listViews or lists in a layout.

If you don't have any views, for example it's happening randomly in the background, then i would suggest that its not a UI element issue, so ignore textfields and such. It could be a background service that's storing information in a cursor or requesting a cursor.

Also, does the issue arise from your app? or perhaps someone else's that you've installed recently. List the full logCat trace. Someone might recognise the issue.

I would hazard a guess that if you haven't written something specific around this that its someone elses log message, or perhaps that of a library your using?