# W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1066): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

Tags: android

Here is my class:

```
public class Insert extends Activity 
{

    EditText name,surname,age;
    Button insert;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.insert);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        name =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        surname =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.surname);
        age =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
        insert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.click);
        insert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
              public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String nm = name.getText().toString();
                String ct = surname.getText().toString();
                String emailid = age.getText().toString();
                 insertRecords(nm, ct, emailid);
              }
            private void insertRecords(String nm,String ct,String emailid)
            {
                 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", nm));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("surname",ct));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age",emailid));
                    sendData(nameValuePairs);
            }
            private void sendData(ArrayList<NameValuePair> data)
            {
                try 
                {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:81/new/insert.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

In LogCat

```
04-23 12:12:10.263: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1066): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: can any one help me out with this error

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633188/android-input-connection-error

Comment: To get a (good) response, please explain more and better the error you get, where, what's do your app, what are you trying, etc... And put a better tittle too, must be a simple/short explanation of your problem

Comment: Honestly, I think the answer to the question question @GaryKerr linked to is a red herring, since InputConnection is not related at all to InputStreams, which have a close() method. Personally, I believe these messages are part of the pervasive log spam you get on Android and are not necessarily related to any programming errors. For example, this can happen if the soft keyboard is open when an Activity is destroyed, but that is not a programming error.

Comment: add this line:  httpClient.getConnectionManager().closeIdleConnections();

Answer (score 1):

Such problems occur when the input connection in the previous page(or class) has not been closed. Check whether you've closed the input connection in the previous class (by giving connection.close()).

This problem arises when you leave the activity and keep an HTTP connection open. To prevent that, you can try calling

```
httpClient.getConnectionManager().closeIdleConnections();
```

You can read the documentation for this method [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpConnectionManager.html#closeIdleConnections(long)).

Comment: InputConnection is not at all related to HTTP connections, it's related to InputMethods.

Comment: Thats enough for me!