# Why am I unable to print my ArrayList generated from my SQLite table?

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

Android developer. I have an SQLite database. One of my columns is called KEY_SWITCH. I want to convert the integers in this list into an ArrayList and then print it to my console.

Here's my code:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getAllIntegerValues() {
    ArrayList<Integer> yourIntegerValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Cursor result = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,
            new String[] {KEY_SWITCH}, null, null, null, null,
            null, null);

    if (result.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            yourIntegerValues.add(result.getInt(result
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_SWITCH)));
        } while (result.moveToNext());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    System.out.print(yourIntegerValues);
    return yourIntegerValues;
}
```

I run the code like this

```
DBAdapter_Metrics mydbmetric;

private SQLiteDatabase dbmetric;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_metric_list);
    openDBMetrics();
    populateListViewFromDNewBMetric();
    mydbmetric.getAllIntegerValues();
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error: 
`endAllActiveAnimators on 0x915c1380 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x8f550150`

Why isn't it printing my ArrayList?

I tried to search about this error but I found the error changes depending on where in my code I launch the `getAllIntegerValues()`

For example, when I created a drop down menu with an option to run it, I got this error

`endAllActiveAnimators on 0x8e3b5300 (MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView) with handle 0x8ef83f50`

So it seems to shift depending on where I run it, which I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

do it like below:

```
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(yourIntegerValues.toArray()));
```

UPDATE: another way is like below:

```
System.out.print(android.text.TextUtils.join(",", yourIntegerValues))
```

Comment: That works. However, I now have a separate problem. It only prints one value, 0. This is because every entry in the column is zero. How can I get the ArrayList to all of the values? That is, I want it to print [0 0 0 ..... 0]

Comment: Without println, you just get the original error. The second piece of code also yields the original error.

Comment: the first work is working on my device. no matter if all your datas are 0. even if your entrys are null the first one works !!

Comment: your error is not becuase of the list. there is somethin wrong with animators and animations. did you use any of them in your project ?

Comment: put a try catch and printstacktrace the error. give me the error and i will tell.

Comment: don't know how :'D sorry I tried for like 15 minutes and failed

Comment: try
        {
                mydbmetric.getAllIntegerValues();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: layouts W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633188/android-input-connection-error according to this, could it be related to not having `.close()` statements? I don't use them ever because I didn't know what they were for.